# How to search persons in social networks by name, birthday, location etc

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, xing

I have a project, i have to search people by some fields (name, birthday, location, education, email etc.) in social networks (for example: Facebook, LinkedIn, Xing, G+, maybe also in wikipedia).

I wanted to use Facebook Graph Api to search people, i can search by name but i only get first and last name of users and not more info about the users.

What can you prefer me, to search people by this fields and get results?

Answer (score 1):

The Search API only offers a search by name and you will only get (App Scoped) IDs in return, you can´t search for anything else with the Graph API. This is mostly for privacy reasons, i assume. I would not want anyone to search for my name and get my email, and vice versa.

See the docs for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Comment: I don't want get any email from any person. I want only  verify that the person is registered in any social media. If he marks his infos as publish, why not? i should get them. Because we can see many people's (who is not in our friendlist) information on their profile. I speak not only for facebook, also for linkedin and xing its important for me.

Comment: even if stuff is public on facebook, it does not mean you are allowed to grab it - scraping is not allowed and for any details you need to authorize the user. anyway, the only way to search for users is by their name, and you will only get their (app scoped) ID in return.

Comment: you know, people may not want you to connect their profile on your website with their personal profile on facebook (or other platforms). you should always let them connect their profiles on their own, if they want to.

Comment: Actually, what i wanted to is, i want to search people in social networks by these fields. thats mean, i already know his email adress, location etc. only to search by these fields and get results

Comment: as i´ve already pointed out in my answer, that´s not possible. you can only search by name.